# How to stop audio from other app when my app is in Foreground [Objective C]

Tags: spotify, avplayer, avaudiosession, mpmovieplayer

I'm building an audio app and I'm looking for solution to stop other sound sources (from other app) when the user open my app. 
By example, if I listened a track with spotify in background, when I open my app, this track should stop.

Spotify already do this thing .

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the track and not just mute it I think you have to send a key shortcut.

If you want to mute it you can use CoreAudio and MixerProNet. They will also let you adjust the volume of each source which was what I wanted to do. Require Vista or later.